# Bad attempt to compute absolute value

Tags: java, jenkins

```
        int server = (Math.abs(q.hashCode()) % solrLoadBalanceNumOfServers) + 1;
```

Jenkins is warning me with this note:

> Bad attempt to compute absolute value of signed 32-bit hashcode

This code generates a hashcode and then computes the absolute value of that hashcode. If the hashcode is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, then the result will be negative as well (since `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE`).

One out of 2^32 strings have a hashCode of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, including "polygenelubricants" "GydZG_" and ""DESIGNING WORKHOUSES".

Does anyone know why I got this warning for this compute absolute value?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why I got this warning for this  compute absolute value

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The warning itself explains why you're getting the warning.

You're calling `Math.abs()` on a hashcode. Integers go from −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Since the maximum is 2,147,483,647, `Math.abs(-2,147,483,648)` returns -2,147,483,648 because there is no 2,147,483,648. If your String hashcodes to -2,147,483,648, then the `server` variable will be assigned to a negative value, which may cause the query to be dropped or your service to crash.

Rather than do it that way, just do the modulus first and then call `Math.abs()`.

```
int server = Math.abs(q.hashCode() % solrLoadBalanceNumOfServers) + 1;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the +1 be outside the abs? Mod can return a negative number in java.

Comment: I don't understand how the +1 can solve that. Moreover it looks like it will drastically increase the number of out of bound exception the way it's done. Let's say you got 10 servers, MIN_INT % 10 will give -8...+1 = -7. If think the real solution is to have a special handling of MIN_INT. But thx !

Comment: The +1 is present in the original question, so I preserved it. The effect of the code I wrote is to map any possible result of q.hashCode() to a value between 1 and solrLoadBalanceNumOfServers inclusive. The thrust of my solution is that you do mod first, Math.abs() second.

Answer (score 3):

First the error is likely coming from FindBugs([link](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RV_ABSOLUTE_VALUE_OF_HASHCODE))  not Jenkins itself. It is just being run/shown in Jenkins.

Integer.MIN_VALUE = -(2^31) and a Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2^31-1. So from a purely mathematical perspective the absolute value of Integer.MIN_VALUE does NOT equal Integer.MAX_VALUE. It will come up infrequently and could cause issues, which is why it is warning you.